# Ubuntu 14.04 is struck at boot screen

Tags: ubuntu, boot, kernel-panic

Ubuntu 14.04 is struck at boot screen

This box is running on vmware esxi, following is the boot screen

[image]

I tried interrupting boot using following options

1. holding shift key
2. pressing escape key

But none of them worked, How to interrupt boot and get into single user mode?

Comment: Single user mode requires that at least `/` gets mounted, which appears to be what is failing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cannot [enter rescue mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/ch08s07.html) from the boot menu, probably due to [VMWare](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/435192), you might want to try using a [live cd](https://mediawiki.middlebury.edu/wiki/LIS/Troubleshooting_with_Ubuntu_Live_CD) to fix the problem.